# Selenium Python Automation

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I have a table with multiple pages. I want to select say 5 elements from the table and click on the checkbox corresponding to those at a time. How is that possible through selenium python automation

```
 def __init__(self, env):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.maximize_window()

    if env == 'Staging':
        self.driver.get("https://serviceconsole-stg.tivo.com/serviceconsole/login.action")
    elif env == 'QE':
        self.driver.get("http://serviceconsolese01.tivo.com:9090/serviceconsole")
    else:
        print "Environment is not available", env
        print "\n Supported Environments are Staging and QE"
        self.driver.quit()
        raise SystemExit("Program Exited")

    with open('config.json','r') as user_credentials:
            config = json.load(user_credentials)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(config['user']['name'])
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(config['user']['password'])
    self.driver.find_element_by_id("signIn").click()
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "loginValidationError"]')
        print "Login Not successful"
        self.driver.quit()
        raise SystemExit("Program Exited")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Login Successful"

def addnewlinearpackage(self, title, enddate_days_from_today):
    try:
        # Select Manage
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='configuration-tab']").click()

        # Creating new Linear Package
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("linearpublishing").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("linpub").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("addLinearPackage").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("linearpackageTitle").send_keys(title)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('tempPackageId').send_keys(
            datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("inlineLinearPackageCheckbox").click()

        start_time = self.driver.find_element_by_id('startDate')
        execute = start_time.find_element_by_xpath("*//span[@class='fa fa-calendar']")
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", execute)
        time.sleep(7)

        end_time = self.driver.find_element_by_id('endDate')
        end_time.find_element_by_xpath("*//span[@class='fa fa-calendar']").click()
        end_date = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=enddate_days_from_today)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//td[@data-day='" + end_date + "']").click()
        time.sleep(7)

    except NoSuchElementException as exp:
        print exp
        self.driver.quit()
        raise SystemExit("Program Exited")

def addlinearservice(self, serviceId):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("linearServiceSection").click()
        time.sleep(10)

        self.driver.find_element_by_id("publishLinearPackageBtn").click()
        time.sleep(30)

        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("sorting_1")

        linear_service_found = False

        # Searching existing linear service
        if linear_service_found == False:

            try:# Search in first page
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[9]/a").click()

                if self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(serviceId).is_displayed():
                    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        "//a[contains(text(),'" + serviceId + "')]/following::td/input[@type='checkbox']").click()
                    linear_service_found = True
                    print "Linear service found"

            except NoSuchElementException:
                print"No such Element found in page 1"

            try:

                while linear_service_found == False:  # loop to navigate to next page till finding the service ID

                    try:  # Search till last page is reached and next button is disabled

                        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "// *[@id = 'associatedLinearServicesTable1_next']/../li[@class ='paginate_button next disabled']")
                        print 'No further Page available to search'
                        break

                    except NoSuchElementException:

                        try:
                            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[9]/a').click()
                            if self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(serviceId).is_displayed():
                                # click the checkbox of Service ID
                                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                    "//a[contains(text(),'" + serviceId + "')]/following::td/input[@type='checkbox']").click()

                                linear_service_found = True
                                print "Linear Service found"
                                break

                        except NoSuchElementException:
                            print "No such Element found in current page"

            except NoSuchElementException:
                print"No such Element found"

            if linear_service_found == True:
                time.sleep(10)
                #Click on Save button
                self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ html / body / div[4] / div / div / div[3] / button[1]').click()
                time.sleep(10)

    except NoSuchElementException as exp:
        print exp
        self.driver.quit()
        raise SystemExit("Program Exited")

def publish(self):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Publish")]').click()
        time.sleep(5)

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirmDialogOk"]').click()
        time.sleep(10)

        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="appSuccessMsg"]')
            print("Linear Package Published Successfully")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print ("Linear Package NOT PUBLISHED.. check the Error Message in Service console webpage")
            time.sleep(60)
            self.driver.quit()
            raise SystemExit("Program Exited")

    except NoSuchElementException as exp:
            print exp
            self.driver.quit()
            raise SystemExit("Program Exited")

def exit(self):
    print("Exiting.....")
    time.sleep(5)
    self.driver.quit()
```

Please find the full code. This code works only for selecting one element. I have to select multiple elements.

**image**

Comment: can't you post your code?

Comment: Please edit your question next time, instead of posting your code as a comment. It is also helpful to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Vidhya, you just want to know how to mark checkboxes or you want to know how you can select all those checkboxes and then mark them?

Answer (score 1):

If the checkboxes have a common locator, you can use `find_elements_by_xpath` instead of `find_element_by_xpath`. This will return a list of WebElements, which you can then iterate over to click the boxes.